# configuring load/traffic split using haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I have two app servers which are behind an haproxy load balancer. Is there a configuration available using which I can split the traffic between the two as per my requirement. Like sending x% of the requests to server A and rest to server B.

Comment: Have you looked into this at all? The question shows no attempt at researching the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide your traffic with "weight" directive. For example:

```
server appA 10.0.0.1:8000 maxconn 800 weight 3 check fall 1
server appB 10.0.0.2:8000 maxconn 800 weight 1 check fall 1
```